# Parse complicated format in C#

Tags: c#

I have text format that need to parse in C#. Each test have to be parsed one at a time. Text file format as following:

```
 T1 
  {
     data1=3.5
     data2=58%
     data3=FAIL
  }

   T2
   {
      data1=7.5
      data2=78%
      data3=PASS
   }
```

The data class that will be like this:

```
Class data
{
   double measure;
   double percentage;
   string testR;
}
```

after parsing text file, for example, the first T1 will be measure=3.5, percentage=58% and testR="FAIL". How can I parse T1 one at a time?

Comment: Please add more information, like you class structure, your attempts so far..

Comment: give more information about input file...its hard to find data in such format.

Comment: So there is a text file containing formatted text as shown in the first code snippet? What are you parsing from?

Comment: I am not following your last comment in the post… _”after parsing text file_”??? If you have already parsed the text file, then what is left to parse?

Comment: It isn't clear from the question whether this is a format that you've made up yourself; but if it is, I would strongly suggest that you consider using a more widely supported format like XML for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2  Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to parse the text; but without knowing the grammar for this unspecified format, I can't help any more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that quite quickly and efficiently with a Regex based LALR parser:

```
    string text = @" T1 
       {
          data1=3.5
          data2=58%
          data3=FAIL
       }

        T2
        {
           data1=7.5
           data2=78%
           data3=PASS
        }";
    string regex = "[ \n\r\t]*([^ \n\r\t{]*)[ \n\r\t]*{[ \n\r\t]*data1=([^ \n\r\t]*)[ \n\r\t]*data2=([^ \n\r\t]*)[ \n\r\t]*data3=([^ \n\r\t]*)[ \n\r\t]*}";
    while(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(text, regex)) {
        var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(text, regex);
        Console.WriteLine($"Item name {match.Groups[1].Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Data1= {match.Groups[2].Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Data2= {match.Groups[3].Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Data3= {match.Groups[4].Value}");
        text = text.Substring(match.Groups[0].Value.Length);
    }
```

You get the following output:

```
Item name T1
Data1= 3.5
Data2= 58%
Data3= FAIL
Item name T2
Data1= 7.5
Data2= 78%
Data3= PASS
```

You can see more information on how to use regular expressions here:
https://regexone.com/references/csharp

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to solve this issue? Can you post your code please? Essentially it is not difficult but you need to keep track on where you are in the inputfile, and you need to break the problem into small pieces. A good start would be to be able to recognize the start and end of one reading. It looks like the { and } might serve that purpose.